# How do I pass a rapidjson::Value& to a function?

Tags: c++, rapidjson

```
rapidjson::Document doc;
//parse doc
const rapidjson::Value& object = doc["Object"];
checkSomething(object);

checkSomething(const rapidjson::Value& object) const
{
//do something with it
}
```

I am trying to pass a part of the JSON document to a function.

How do I correctly pass an object like this?

It works perfectly fine when I try it like this:

```
rapidjson::Document doc;
//parse doc
checkSomething(doc["Object"]);

checkSomething(const rapidjson::Value& object) const
{
//do something with it
}
```

How do I have to reference the `object` for it to work?

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: Did you mean to add `const` to the type of `object` in first definition of `checkSomething`? As it stands your two snippets are equivalent

Answer (score 1):

You have a reference to a `const rapidjson::Value`, you can't drop the `const`.

Either change the function to take `const rapidjson::Value &`, or change `object` to not be a const reference `rapidjson::Value& object = doc["Object"];`